# managing the lifetime of transient webhooks?

Tags: webhooks

Imagine I have a (ReST) API which provides access to versions of a resource. In order to achieve a lower latency I want push out notifications of a new resource as it becomes available. One way to do this is to use [webhooks](https://brandur.org/webhooks). 
Webhooks seem to be typically viewed as long lived (days, weeks...) or semi-permanent resources. 
Nowadays we can now upgrade connections to websockets for relatively short-lived low latency sessions.

I think there is still a middle ground where clients create transient webhooks to receive real-time notifications.
For a semi-permanent resource it makes sense for the subscription to be managed by the client. 
For a transient webhook we need the server to manage the life-time of web-hooks in case a client forgets to delete them itself.

I haven't seen any discussion of this kind of webhook online. **Is *transient webhook* the correct term?**

**Are there any best practices for when to automatically delete them?**

If the client forgets to or cannot send the DELETE when should the server delete the resource?
Should the reply to the original POST include a time-to-live?
Should it post a probe heart-beat periodically and keep the hook if there is no reply after N attempts?
When server decides that /foobar/webhooks/ can be deleted should it become a 410 GONE or a 404?

It seems like there is good scope here for some standardisation to avoid all the potential pitfalls.

I would accept an answer (comments also welcome) that improves on my own and links to one or more well documented approaches to this or describes some good patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be something like:

- The webhooks for a ReST resource */foobar* reside under */foobar/webhooks/*
- A specific web-hook would reside under */foobar/webhooks/*
- A client sends an HTTP POST to */foobar/webhooks* to create a subscription.
- The client optionally includes an indication of how long it expects to need it.
- The server replies with a 202 ACCEPT and the location of the webhook */foobar/webhooks/*
- That webhook should provide the a time-to-live indication.
- When it is done the client sends an HTTP DELETE to */foobar/webhooks/*
- If the client wants the hook to last longer it should tell the server by posting to */foobar/webhooks/* with a message asking it to keep 
  the hook alive longer.

You also need to be mindful of security, which is discussed well [here](http://resthooks.org/docs/security/).

Another resource is:
https://realtimeapi.io/hub/rest-hooks/